# javascript - why doesnt this work?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

```
<form method="post" action="sendmail.php" name="Email_form">
Message ID <input type="text" name="message_id" /><br/><br/>
Aggressive conduct <input type="radio" name="conduct" value="aggressive contact" /><br/><br/>
Offensive conduct <input type="radio" name="conduct" value="offensive conduct" /><br/><br/>
Rasical conduct <input type="radio" name="conduct" value="Rasical conduct" /><br/><br/>
Intimidating conduct <input type="radio" name="conduct" value="intimidating conduct" /><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Mail" onclick=validate() />
</form>
```

```
    window.onload = init;  
    function init()     
    {          
        document.forms["Email_form"].onsubmit = function() 
        {                                                                 
            validate();                                                                 
            return false;                                                             

        };     
    } 

    function validate() 
    {     
        var form = document.forms["Email_form"]; //Try avoiding space in form name.     
        if(form.elements["message_id"].value == "") { //No value in the "message_id" 
            box     
            {         
                alert("Enter Message Id");         
                //Alert is not a very good idea.          
                //You may want to add a span per element for the error message        
                //An div/span at the form level to populate the error message is also ok        
                //Populate this div or span with the error message         
                //document.getElementById("errorDivId").innerHTML = "No message id";

                 return false;  //There is an error. Don't proceed with form submission.

            } 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Am i missing something or am i just being stupid?

edit*** 
sorry i should add! the problem is that i want the javascript to stop users going to 'sendmail.php' if they have not entered a message id and clicked a radio button... at the moment this does not do this and sends blank emails if nothing is inputted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the underscore when identifying the form:

```
document.forms["Email_form"].onsubmit = ...
```

EDIT:

```
document.forms["Email_form"].onsubmit = function() {
    return validate();
};

function validate() {
    var form = document.forms["Email_form"];
    if (form.elements["message_id"].value == "") {
        alert("Enter Message Id");
        return false;
    }
    var conduct = form.elements['conduct']; //Grab radio buttons
    var conductValue; //Store the selected value
    for (var i = 0; i<conduct.length; i++) { //Loop through the list and find selected value
        if(conduct[i].checked) { conductValue = conduct[i].value } //Store it
    }
    if (conductValue == undefined) { //Check to make sure we have a value, otherwise fail and alert the user
        alert("Enter Conduct");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

return the value of validate.  Validate should return true if your validation succeeds, and false otherwise.  If the onsubmit function returns false, the page won't change.

EDIT: Added code to check the radio button.  You should consider using a javascript framework to make your life easier.  Also, you should remove the onclick attribute from your submit input button as validation should be handled in the submit even, not the button's click

Comment: your edit did not work. It still submitted empty inputs to the 'sendmail.php' which then emailed an empty email

Comment: yes it work there. Do you think maybe the javascript on my pc is disabled? Also when i tested your code if i entered a message id but not a radio button it sent to next page. I want it so a radio button must be clicked

Comment: okay i tested again and it works! Can you edit so that it has my requirements for radio buttons please

Answer (score 4):

You are using

```
validate();
return false;
```

...which means that the submit event handler always returns false, and always fails to submit. You need to use this instead:

```
return validate();
```

Also, where you use `document.forms["Email form"]` the space should be an underscore.

---

Here's a completely rewritten example that uses modern, standards-compliant, organised code, and works:

http://jsbin.com/eqozah/3

Note that a successful submission of the form will take you to 'sendmail.php', which doesn't actually exist on the jsbin.com server, and you'll get an error, but you know what I mean.

Here is an updated version that dumbs down the methods used so that it works with Internet Explorer, as well as includes radio button validation:

http://jsbin.com/eqozah/5

Comment: Your code contains many outdated methods and is generally poorly written, so debugging it will be difficult. I'll whip up a working example that is functionally equivalent, but uses modern, correct code, and add it to my answer.

Comment: Okay thank you! The code was taken from else where, i did not write it myself

Comment: Not a problem. Do yourself a favour and never get code from that place again; I feel like I've travelled back in time to the dark ages of JavaScript.

Comment: @Delean Azabani thanks, but on my pc when i click send mail with nothing it it just goes to the error page. Do you think it something wrong with my computer eg javascript disabled?

Comment: What browser and browser version are you using?

Comment: erm im pretty sure its the newest version on IE... would you like to move this to chat?

Comment: I'm a bit apprehensive of the 'chat' feature; these comments are important to the issue diagnosis and they should probably stay here. In response to your browser, the latest *stable* version of Internet Explorer, version 8, lacks support for the *standard* event handler things like `addEventListener` and `preventDefault`, and `querySelector`. I'll edit my answer with a solution that works both for IE's non-standard nonsense, as well as the other browsers' standard implementation. Please note that you really should switch to a better browser like Firefox, especially as a web developer.

Comment: if you look further down the page at Dennis answer that worked for me although the code was not everything i asked for

Comment: Hey, I've updated my answer to make it work in Internet Explorer, as well as validate that a radio button is clicked. Let me know if it works (I don't have any computers with Internet Explorer installed, though I've changed the code to use IE-friendly methods from my past memories with IE development, and it should work).

Comment: hey, nope still doesnt work on either the web address you gave or in my own code

Comment: I'm afraid I've reached my capacity to help you, as I don't have Internet Explorer to find what isn't working. Unless Internet Explorer is a requirement for your application, you really should be using a better browser that supports such basic web standards. If you test the examples in Firefox, Chrome, Opera or most other browsers, they will work.

Comment: I would like my website to work in all web browsers to maximise the potential of users. The main 2 i would like would be IE and firefox. As i am still learning to do all this i am unsure how to but am developing in my browser IE as it stands. Thanks Anyways

Comment: As a web developer, the best way to write web applications is to develop it and test it against a proper web browser, and then add 'hacks' for the incorrect web browsers, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Most obvious error, your form has name attribute 'Email_form', but in your Javascript you reference `document.forms["Email form"]`. The ironic thing is, you even have a comment in there not to use spaces in your form names :)

Comment: the code was taken from elsewhere and i edited to my own needs so i just left comment in